# r as.Date switching my year and month

Tags: r, as.date

I have a character string that is a date (month, day, year).

```
char <- "12/1/2014"
```

When I try to turn this character string into a date, and I specify month,day, year

```
date <- as.Date(char, origin = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

it formats it like I put in year, day, month:

```
> date
[1] "0012-01-20"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use `lubridate::mdy(char)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the format using the `format` argument, not the `origin` argument.

```
(date <- as.Date("12/1/2014", format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] "2014-12-01"
```

Comment: Of course. Thank you!